# Creating a trailing line with three.js

Tags: three.js

[This](http://barkofthebyte.azurewebsites.net/demos/drawlineplane.htm) is very similar to what I want.

Except I'd like the user to see a trailing line after first click. So when the user first clicks starting position is fixed and a line is created where the end point would be the current mouse location. Similarly to MS Paint line drawing functionality.

So when I move mouse to the right I want to see the line change.

Maybe some examples or pointers how to implement it?

[image: example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, first initiate a two point line

```
var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

geometry.vertices.push(point);
geometry.vertices.push(point);

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({}));
```

Then on mousemove replace the last vertice with latest mouse position.

```
line.geometry.vertices[last_point] = new_point;
```